# Multiple "More" links for the_excerpt(); in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I've changed my excerpt link in wordpress from "[...]" to "Read More" with the code below. I want to know if there is a way to use more than one link for the excerpt. Let's say for posts in one category have "Read More" for their excerpt, and then posts in another category have "See Photos" for their excerpt link. is this possible?

```
remove_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt');
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'custom_trim_excerpt');

function custom_trim_excerpt($text) { // Fakes an excerpt if needed
global $post;
if ( '' == $text ) {
$text = get_the_content('');
$text = apply_filters('the_content', $text);
$text = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $text);
$text = strip_tags($text);
$excerpt_length = 24;
$words = explode(' ', $text, $excerpt_length + 1);
if (count($words) > $excerpt_length) {
array_pop($words);
array_push($words, '...<br /><a href="'.get_permalink().'" class="tag">Read More</a>');
$text = implode(' ', $words);
}
}
return $text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

yes you can do it. use **excerpt_more** filter to change the "[...]" and in_category function to check the category for read more text.

try this code.

```
function custom_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    $read_more_txt = 'Read More..';

    if (in_category('cat_slug'))
        $read_more_txt = 'See Photos..';
    else if (in_category('cat_slug2'))
        $read_more_txt = 'Something else..';

    return ' <a title="'. $read_more_txt .'" href="'. get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) .'">'.   $read_more_txt .'</a>'; 
} 
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'custom_excerpt_more' );
```

Comment: Hey Nick, That might work if I didn't already have a filter that extended the excerpt and change the more link, but it doesn't work with the function I have above. Is there anyway I could add what you are trying to do to the above function I've already got working to give me multiple "more" links? Something like you have (based on category slugs" would be perfect.

Comment: Hi,
yeah keep the read more text in a variable and check for in_category('cat_slug'); so you can assign different different value to read more variable according to category.